# Best tools/frameworks/approaches to test structure of the .Net Framework solution

Tags: .net, testing

I'm looking for a tool/framework to test the structure of the .Net Framework Solution(not structure of the unit test projects).

Example of the tests:

Since I switched my solution from package.config to PackageReference, I'd like to have a test to be sure there isn't any package.config file in any project of my solution(so I will be sure no one will add new project with package.config in our solution).

Does anybody know best practices/tools/frameworks for tests like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some research we decided:

1. **Pester**

   Actually it's a module for PowerShell scripts ([source code](https://github.com/pester/Pester)), but it contains a 
   lot of things from unit testing like asserts, mocks and output. It's quite easy to 
   write simple scenarios(like I described in description). One me profit using that 
   it's simple integration with CI. 
   So it was designed for PowerShell, but in some cases it will be good tool for fitness 
   tests
2. **Using xUnit/NUnit as a framework for fitness tests**.

   In some cases if you don't want to introduce new modules/languages/technologies in a 
   solution, we are still able using xUnit/NUnit.

   So in that case we can writing tests on the same languages, but in comparing with 
   Pester some test scenarios may be harder to create

In our project we looked at these 2 tools and the xUnit was used for tests, but Pester looked quite interesting for us as well.

I just left here, maybe someone will find that useful